# How to write a custom keras layer to resample a 3D volume?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-resizing, volume

I have a tensor `(batch_size, height, width, depth, channel)`(representing 3D volumes) inside the network, which needs to be resampled. I am considering writing a custom keras layer to do this.

```py
input = Input()
x = net(input) # another network
x = custom_resample_3d(...)(x)
x = ...
```

The output of `net` is let's say `(batch_size, 64, 64, 64, 1)`. I want to resize the tensor to `(batch_size, 256, 256, 32, 1)` using interpolation.

So my initial thought would be like customizing a keras layer with `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom`.

```py
class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        return scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(x, ...)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return ...
```

Is there any better way for this? Or do I need to convert the `keras tensor` to numpy array and then convert it back as a tensor?

Answer (score 0):

If you havent figured this out yet in TF, you can use the library [TorchIO](https://torchio.readthedocs.io/transforms/preprocessing.html) with the resample function to reszie. You will need to know the affine space to do so.